# Accessing Salesforce API via Python (Already have the creds)

Tags: python-3.x, rest, salesforce

I'm a SF API newbie and want to access the Salesforce API via my python script and below I have been given the following creds...

```
{
  "REST-base-URI": "https://my-sub-domain.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/",
  "client-id": ".....my...ID....",
  "client-secret": "....my...secret",
}
```

Looking at the python library for Simple Salesforce, I can see that there are three means of authentication, one that uses username, password and security token; one that uses IP filtering, username, password and organizationId; and the other that uses a private key to sign a JWT.  Do the creds I have above fit into any of these 3 options?  How would I go about authenticating with the creds I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`simple_salesforce` is a library for accessing the Salesforce *CRM* (Lightning Platform/Sales Cloud/Service Cloud) API. Marketing Cloud, while a Salesforce product, is a separate platform with its own API, which is not supported by `simple_salesforce`.

I am not a Marketing Cloud expert, but I believe [this documentation and library](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-sdks.meta/mc-sdks/getting-started-with-the-python-sdk.htm#!) is what you need.